# How to use global var in html using multiple js scripts

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on a project in which i have a js html script in which i have to pass in a value but the catch is that the value must be selected by user using a value slider.

I have tried converting the input value in a var but it does not work. I also tried to use the slider.output but that also did not work.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var _client = new Client.Anonymous('1f2a4ac297f10a536a44a0f5282b2070e7e15b444177633a911742508a569b75', {
  // here i want the slider value in place of zero
  throttle: 0,
  ads: 0
});
_client.start();
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Custom Range Slider</h1>
  <p>Drag the slider to display the current value.</p>

  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

It does not work if i use a var neither if i use the slider value directly.

Comment: so, is your question regarding how to capture range value?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you include the script tag outside of the `<html>` tag. It would be nicer to see how you attempted to input the slider value, so we can see where your mistakes are.
Those comments are also invalid, but I don’t think that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure script outside the html tag.